# How does the lifecycle of a React component defined as a function in differ from a component defined as a class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to better understand the lifecycle process of a component in React - basically, what all occurs during mounting/updating/unmounting.

I found this excellent resource that describes the lifecycle of a class based component in React: https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_lifecycle.asp

However, now that components should generally be defined as functions, is there another resource that explains the lifecycle for function-based components? There area bunch of blog posts that describe why some old class based methods are unsafe (ex: https://legacy.reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html), but I can't find anything that describes a components lifecycle in the new documentation.

Really, I just want an explanation of what happens during mounting/unmounting of function based components in React - what methods are executed (ie `render`?), etc.